# Rewrite URLs to subdomain using htaccess and wild card DNS

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to change my website URL
http://domain.tk/site/google.com
To
google.com.domain.tk
I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^site/([^/]+)/?$ http://$1.domain.tk/ [NC,R=301,L]
```

it redirects to google.com.domain.tk and show the homepage content instead of the content in http://domain.tk/site/google.com

Example of what i want can be found on this [website](https://websiteoutlook.com)

Comment: Well, you implemented an explicit redirection for requests to `site/...` to the absolute URL `https://....domain.tk/`. That is what happens. As to be expected.

Comment: Maybe you want to start reading a bit into the documentation of the tool you are using? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: I have been struggling to make this work for over a week now. I have read the docs over and over but am still unable to make work.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation I referred to in my comment to your question clearly states and demonstrates in examples that the order of arguments in a redirection rule is 1. matching pattern applied to the path component of the incoming request and 2. the target path or URL the request should internally get rewritten to. The rule you implemented does the opposite of what you ask: you implemented an external redirection to exactly that host name you want to rewrite *from* .

This example should get you going:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^google\.com\.domain\.tk$
RewriteRule ^ /site/google.com%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA]
```

For this to work the rewriting module has to be loaded into the http server, obviously and it has to be activated for the host. You should implement such rules in the actual host configuration inside your http server. If you do not have access to that (so if you are using a cheap hosting provider) then you can instead use a distributed configuration file (often named ".htaccess"), but that needs to be enabled in the host configuration first and it comes with a performance penalty.